# xsd regex pattern restriction for value with periods

Tags: xml, regex, xsd

I need to restrict a string type attribute in xsd to a value with pattern x.x.x.x 
 where:

```
- X is any character or number or symbol eg >?, but not any white space (space, carriage 
  return etc) at s
- . is just single period
```

so example value are:

```
rob.jones.male.65

ste%ve.d.445.£dd
```

invalid patterns are:

```
rob..male.65

rob.jones. male.65

rob.jones.65
```

Answer (score 0):

Any reason you can't use

```
[^\. &#x09;&#x0A;]+(\.[^\. &#x09;&#x0A;]+)*
```

?

Comment: Hi, thanks for response. your suggeston: [^\.]+(\.[^\.]+)* matched any string with a period. I modified slightly to "[\S.]+(\.[\S.]+){3}, however it will match strings with more than 3 periods. I'm guessing because the ^ is including periods itself. what is syntax for any char except period?